# How to play Windows audio to a WiFi speaker?

Tags: windows, windows-11, speakers

I'd like to play my whole PC (Windows 11) audio to my Sonos WiFi speaker, and I can't find out how.
Does anyone know?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Welcome to Super User. Questions must demonstrate a reasonable amount of research & understanding of the problem being solved. Please edit to either a) clearly describe your problem and the research done so far to solve it or b) include attempted solutions plus why they didn't work. In either case, be sure your expected results are clearly presented.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sonos WiFi speakers are **not** Bluetooth computer speakers; rather, they stream audio from the internet through a WiFi router. In order to use them as *computer* speakers, you must use applications on the PC to "broadcast" (well, *podcast*) the audio.

Using the Sonos desktop app or a streaming app that Sonos supports (like Apple Music, Spotify, Amazon Music or Deezer) is limiting because **only the *source* selected for that app** will play -- not other sounds, such as a Zoom call or system beeps.

According to [Gear Patrol](https://www.gearpatrol.com/tech/a438981/how-to-use-sonos-as-computer-speakers/), " If you have a pair of Ones or One SLs and have them configured in a stereo pair, you can then use a Sonos Port (***US$449***)," to podcast over your WiFi network.

"If you have a pair of Five or Play:5 speakers, you can bypass the need for a Port because the speakers already have a line-in connection. You can connect one of the speakers directly to your computer (via a 3.5mm to 3.5mm cable) and set it as your computer's default sound output." Of course, now you're using one speaker *wired*, rather than WiFi.

"[T]here's another big reason why you shouldn't using Sonos speakers as computer speakers: the audio/video delay." Input is buffered and processed, so there will be a [small but] noticeable delay [30-75 ms] between audio output and what you hear.

So, on the basis of what Gear Patrol states, you'd be far better off for most purposes getting a pair of wired (or Bluetooth) speakers. On Amazon, for example, I see highly rated wired speakers from US$14 and up, and lesser-rated Bluetooth speakers starting at that price, too. BTW, my experience on Windows is that Bluetooth is *not* reliable for a long-term connection. If you *must* have wireless speakers, consider an FM modulator (e.g., this [DIY model](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B08PVBZB8F)) and any FM receiver as a more reliable option.